# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass in render action error flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form which takes the rails model `FlsCenter` and orders them alphabetically to be displayed in a drop down. When none of the fields of the form are filled out, and the form is submitted, the page gets a 500 Server Error in which the following Rails error is displayed:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Where the `map` function is in the following view code:

```
= f.select(:fls_center, @fls_centers.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, prompt: "Select a Program Center", selected:@school_application.fls_center)
```

Where `@fls_centers` is defined in the `new` method of my `SchoolApplicationController` here:

```
@fls_centers = FlsCenter.order('name ASC')
```

Here are the relevant controller methods from `SchoolApplicationsController`

```
def create
@school_application = SchoolApplication.new(school_application_params)
  if @school_application.save_with_payment
    redirect_to pay_path(id: @school_application.id)
  else  
    @school_application.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      flash.now[:error] = msg
    end
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

And here is my `new` method:

```
  def new
    if application_params 
      @school_application = SchoolApplication.new(application_params)
    else
      @school_application = SchoolApplication.new()
    end 
    Rails.logger.debug(@fls_centers)
    @fls_centers = FlsCenter.order('name ASC')
  end
```

The only thing I can imagine that is going wrong is that `render action: "new"` does not execute the variable instantiation inside the `new` method. I do not know how to amerliorate this situation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are executing `Rails.logger.debug(@fls_centers)` before defining the `@fls_centers`, So make changes like shown below:

```
def new
  @fls_centers = FlsCenter.order('name ASC')
  if application_params 
    @school_application = SchoolApplication.new(application_params)
  else
    @school_application = SchoolApplication.new()
  end 
  Rails.logger.debug(@fls_centers)      
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You guessed right. The actual `new` method does not get executed when you call

```
render action: "new"
```

You will have to call the variable instantiations all over again:

```
def create
@school_application = SchoolApplication.new(school_application_params)
  if @school_application.save_with_payment
    redirect_to pay_path(id: @school_application.id)
  else  
    @school_application.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      flash.now[:error] = msg
    end
    @fls_centers = FlsCenter.order('name ASC')
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

If you have a lot of them it might be better to refactor them in a method and call that method in the `new` method as well as before the `render` call.